# Passing a non-constructor parameter variable to the base class constructor from a derived class causes weird behaviour

Tags: c++

I have the following code, which is a simplification of a problem I previously had in a different project, that exhibits weird behaviour.

```
class A
{
public:
  A()
    : x(12) {}
private:
  int x;
};

class Base
{
public:
  Base(A& a)
    : a(a) {}
protected:
  A a;
};

int main()
{
  A a{};

  class Derived : public Base
  {
  public:
    Derived()
      : Base(a) {}
  };

  Derived d{};

  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles successfully. Assuming that this code is in a file called `mre.cpp`, I compiled it using GCC 9.2 with the following command:

```
g++ -g mre.cpp -o mre
```

At first glance, one might expect that everything is as expected. Notably, ignoring access modifiers, `d.a.x` should equal `12`. To confirm, let us hop into GDB and set up a breakpoint at the line where `return 0` is.

Let's first take a look at `a`. We can do so by running:

```
(gdb) p a
$2 = {x = 12}
```

We can reasonably expect that `d.a.x` would equal `12`. Unfortunately, when we perform:

```
(gdb) p d
$1 = {<Base> = {a = {x = 32767}}, <No data fields>}
```

It is immediately clear that it is not the case. Note that `d.a.x` has a value of `32767`.

Why is this so? Is this undefined behaviour?

Additionally, in my project where the aforementioned problem is simplified by the code above, the project's equivalent to `d` (`system`) shows `"Cannot access memory"` for the portion where the elements of the STL containers in the project's equivalent to `d.a` (`system.componentManager`) would show up in GDB. Here's how it looks like in GDB:

```
(gdb) p system.componentManager
$3 = (planes::engine::ecs::ComponentManager &) @0x7fffffffcb40: {
  typeNameToArrayMap = std::unordered_map with 2 elements<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff3f800000>, 
  typeNameToIndexMap = std::unordered_map with 140734258741248 elements<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>, nextComponentTypeIndex = 2}
```

---

The problem can actually be fixed by changing the `Derived` constructor to

```
Derived(A& a)
  : Base(a) {}
```

and passing `a` as a constructor argument during initialization of `d`, i.e. `Derived d{a}`.

Comment: Please present a self-contained testcase (or [mcve]) demonstrating your issue. That includes your build steps, execution steps, and exactly what commands you pass to gdb.

Comment: This _could_ be a case of static init order fiasco but it's impossible to tell from the snippets of info provided! e.g. we don't even know how you instantiated the `TestSystem` in either case, or where, or when, or with what arguments..

Comment: Are the `system` and `componentManager0` global objects?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, I updated the question. Please let me know if I should provide more information.

Comment: @bartop, they are not. I updated the snippets to provide a better glimpse at my test code.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais You need to provide a full [repro]. There are way to many holes one has to fill in to make sense of the posted code. That makes finding the UB that you inevitably have somewhere impossible. Some things don't add up: You have `componentManager0` and `componentManager`. Are they supposed to be the same? If not, is `componentManager` global? Are you saying that `TestSystem` is a local class? How is `ComponentManager` defined? How are all the used functions of `System` etc. defined? Are you sure you don't have buffer overruns in any of them? Etc.

Comment: @walnut, I updated the question. I included a link to a GitHub Gist where the full definition of the relevant classes are in. I hope it fills the holes that are present in the previous revision of the question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how else to say it, but you need to be posting a **[mcve]**, not extracted snippets and not GitHub links. It's not optional. Help us to help you.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, my apologies. I stubbornly kept assuming that snippets would suffice. I'll put up an MRE that is reflective of the problem I encountered. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, I have now updated the question with the MRE, that is near equivalent to my problem before (I am unable to create an MRE that uses STL containers like my project). I hope it is enough.

Comment: So much better. It's a perfect question now. Thank you :) I notice you already have an answer as a result, or I'd have started work on it :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, thanks. And thank you for your patience as well.

Comment: No problem. For future ref, the MRE requirement isn't _just_ to keep the site clean/reusable and to make questions easy to answer (though that's a big part of it) - if you get into the habit of making one up-front, you'll usually find the bug in the process. It's a valuable debugging skill. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `a` in your `Derived` class constructor

```
Derived()
  : Base(a) {}
```

is the member variable `a` in your Base class, NOT the local variable in `main`.

When you change your `Derived` class constructor to

```
Derived( A& a )
  : Base(a) {}
```

this new function parameter `a` hides the member variable.

To understand further what's going on try renaming your local variable `a`.

e.g.

```
A x;

Derived()
  : Base(x) {}
```

This should tell you that a reference to a local variable in an enclosing function is not allowed.

Comment: I'm slightly (but not completely) surprised that even `-Wextra` doesn't think this code is potentially problematic. Not that the OP is using warning flags ;)

Comment: I realized this after producing the MRE, but I did not immediately write the realization as part of the question. Haha. Nevertheless, thanks!